# Documentation Topics for Experimental-like Questions on Stack?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

I was filtering through some of my old questions when I stumbled upon a [question that I answered myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753303/php-self-including-loop-concept/38753340#38753340).

Context of the question: I had a curiousity, and I experimented. I then posted my results as an answer.

Should this (or questions like it) be documentation material? and if it is should question-askers be suggested to document instead of ask (for questions like these)? (like how it makes suggestions when regex is mentioned)